# RewriteRule different pages per user

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am deciding to create separate profile links for each user who registers on the website. I am using the .htaccess file `RewriteRule` to achieve this. The url I want to achieve should look something like `www.domain.com/username`. (I don't want www.domain.com/users/username)

Now the problem is, if I add a rule like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users.php?username=$1`
it will matchup all URL addresses for www.domain.com, which may direct to any path. Even if I would like to visit `www.domain.com/about` page, it will be redirected to
 `www.domain.com/users.php?username=about`, which I don't want. (Even if the requests was `www.domain.com/products/abc`)

I could apply filters in my users.php to filter such usernames, or if a username is not found in database, redirect to the page, but this means I have to change filters every time I decide to add a new page in my directory (in this case, any). Also, all traffic will be directed through 1 page, which may cause a performance problem.

Please suggest a way to achieve this, as There are websites that work like this. A possible RewriteRule or PHP code to achieve this.

Comment: Is for example `about` an existing file or folder or are you using other rewrite rules for that? You should post your complete `.htaccess` file.

Comment: about.php is another file. Just removing the file extension.

Comment: In that case @MarcinNabiałek's solution should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use just simple rewrite as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)(.*)/?$ index.php
```

All traffic is redirected to index.php and using php I can run specific controllers depending on url. You should also think about. Almost all frameworks use such rule.

Then in your PHP file you should examine

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

variable to route request to specific controllers

Comment: This sounds promising. Can you please tell why you used (.*) twice, and should there be a parenthesis around '/' before '?' (It might be possible it works either way, I've not checked)

Comment: To be honest I think I found similar rule many years ago and it just works. You can of course add some extra rules to redirect domain with www to non-www and similar, but this one is the best to route all trafic to index.php file (-f and -d are for existing files and directories)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /users.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```